# htcaccess redirect subfolder - wrong escaping perhaps?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I did my homework just in case.

I'm trying to redirect din.teknikblogg.nu (and all its pages) to http://teknikblogg.nu

I tried many options but I can't make it work

Any ideas?

this is what I have done so far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^din\.teknikblogg\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://teknikblogg.nu/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule seem perfect.

Did you make *sure* that mod rewrite is enabled?
Is it in a vhost environment or in a `.htaccess` file?

---

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Hi Oliver thanks for replying. It is .htaccess file.  I'm sorry but I'm not a tech expert so I dont really now how to use the RewriteLog directive. Can I use that in .htaccess?